# dig, host, nslookup, chrome browser can resolve hostname, curl can't

Tags: macos, curl, dns, mdns

I'm using macOS Ventura (13.0.1).

Using [4km3/dnsmasq](https://hub.docker.com/r/4km3/dnsmasq) to spin up a DNS server on my local machine. Using subnet `10.6.0.0/16` and assigned static IP `10.6.0.2`. I've added the DNS server IP address in my network settings.

Here's what happening

```
$ dig +short my.domain.test
10.6.0.6
$ host my.domain.test
my.domain.test has address 10.6.0.6
$ nslookup my.domain.test
Server:     10.6.0.2
Address:    10.6.0.2#53

Name:   my.domain.test
Address: 10.6.0.6

$ curl -i -v -4 my.domain.test
* Could not resolve host: my.domain.test
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: my.domain.test
```

When it doesn't work, the DNS server doesn't seem to be queried.

I've found many other post on the same problem but none of them seems to resolve my issue.
To get the API calls to work, I need this to work with `curl`.

[It works on Chrome Browser, doesn't work on Safari]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, curl doesn't care about local DNS. The domain name needs to exist **ON THE INTERNET**. curl looks for records in root servers. So, even if your DNS record resolves, you can't really access them in all the ways you want. Some will work, some won't.

One solution for this would be, register an actual domain name. Then point the domain name to your private IP addresses or whatever you want to point it to. You can have additional DNS server on your local machine.